# Is $f(t) = At^{-2} + Bt^{-3} \le Ct^{-3}$?

Tags: calculus, estimation

I don't have much experience with estimates so I'm not sure if I a bound I have derived is correct. If I have $f(t) = At^{-2} + Bt^{-3}$ on the interval $[\epsilon, 1]$ can I say that

$$
f(t) \le Ct^{-3}.
$$

Is this true? If so, how can it be derived?

Comment: What are $A, B, C$? Arbitrary constants? Then this is definitely not true.

Comment: It should be "on the interval $(0,1]$, since $f$ is not defined for $t=0$.   Are you asking if you can find a $C$? If so, do you know that $A,B$ are positive, or do you want for any $A,B$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ok I've changed the interval to $[\epsilon, 1]$ which is the interval I should have stated originally. $A$, $B$, and $C$ are arbitrary constants.

Comment: @eurocoder Then this is not true. No matter what $\epsilon$ is (as long as it is positive) it will never be true if $A, B$ are positive and $C$ is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search for $C$ satisfying the inequality, then let's start from the end:

$$At^{-2}+Bt^{-3} \leq Ct^{-3}$$

Multiplying both sides by $t^3$ we get

$$At+B \leq C$$

(note that the sign was not reversed since $t$ is positive)

Now since $t\in (0,1]$ (note that $0$ has to be exclude since you take inverse originaly) then the left side is at most $\max(A+B, B)$ depending on whether $A,$ is positive or negative. Thus

$$C:=\max(A+B, B)$$

is a good enough choice.